# Retrieving duplicate value locations from a List<string> inside a Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, but similar questions on retrieving duplicate value pair key values don't go in-depth enough for me to understand how to use it.

I'm currently using a dictionary of lists containing text and using lists.Intersect to compare the lists with each other. How would I go about getting the key value of which two lists have duplicates within them? Here's my code:

```
private string findDuplicates(Dictionary<int, List<string>> lists)
{
    List<string> intersection = new List<string>();
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 13; j++)
        {
            intersection.Add(String.Join(" ", lists[i].Intersect(lists[j])).ToString());

        };
        //Attempt to retrieve value
        if (intersection.Count > 0)
        {
            numberOfDomainsTB.Text += "\nLocations:\nList " + i + " and List " + j;
        }
    };
```

Other methods I see to do this for ordinary dictionaries is:

```
lists.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

But that doesn't compare the lists' internal values.

Thanks.

Comment: Google is there, first look around.

Comment: Why exactly is `lists` a Dictionary? You are using it like an array or List<>.

Comment: Your  `// Attempt to ....` is inside the outer for-loop, intentional?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Because I need to know which lists have which duplicates, so I need to assign each list an index (my bad for calling it an ID, thanks Henk). This is the way I've been recommended to do it.
The logic with the attempt being outside the inner loop was so that I could use the counter values properly. Currently trying it inside the inner loop.

Comment: When your IDs can be enumerated by a for-loop they are not IDs but index values.

Comment: And index values don't have to be used as Keys in a Dictionary, you can access a `List<>` directly (also with `[]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string findDuplicates(Dictionary<int, List<string>> lists)
{
    List<string> intersection = new List<string>();
    int i;
    int j;
    string compare = "";
    for (i = 0; i < lists.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < lists.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            compare = String.Join(" ", lists[i].Intersect(lists[j])).ToString();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(compare))
            {
                intersection.Add(String.Join(" ", lists[i].Intersect(lists[j])).ToString());

            }
        };

    };
}
```

I fixed this by realizing that intersection.Add will always add a new value to the list, regardless of whether it is empty or not. As such, any comparison made would always show matches with every list. So I opted to do Intersect twice: once to store in a string which is then checked if null/empty, and if not then again in the intersection.Add line to actually add the intersecting values.

**NOTE: I didn't need to use a dictionary in the end. It is simply a remnant of the previous attempt to carry out this task. Any ordinary list would work.**